# How do I make a frequency table from a histogram (data set)?

Tags: data, list-manipulation

I have a data set.

```
dataA = {0.37, 0.51, 0.55, 0.78, 0.99, 1.35, 1.49, 1.50, 1.56, 1.61, 
   1.67, 1.70, 1.89, 1.97, 2.05, 2.16, 2.18, 2.32, 2.41, 2.45, 2.48, 
   2.49, 2.50, 2.51, 2.52, 2.53, 2.54, 2.65, 2.75, 2.80, 2.85, 2.99, 
   3.00, 3.15, 3.23, 3.29, 3.44, 3.45, 3.46, 3.47, 3.49, 3.50, 3.51, 
   3.62, 3.65, 3.66, 3.82, 3.84, 3.99, 4.00, 4.12, 4.23, 4.33, 4.44, 
   4.45, 4.46, 4.49, 4.52, 4.62, 4.99, 5.20, 5.40, 5.59, 5.99};
```

I'm able to convert the data to a histogram and analyze the histogram against a binomial distribution. As:

```
Show[Histogram[dataA, {-0.5, 6.5, 1}, "PDF"], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[6, 0.5], x], {x, 0, 7}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]]
```

How do I convert my data set (histogram) to a frequency table?

Comment: I believe you want [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html).  Does that appear to be the case?

Comment: Dear Mister Wizard- I got to home plate with: columncounts=BinCounts[dataA,{-0.5,6.5,1}], Next: columnstotal=Total[columncounts] and last, frequencytable=N[columncounts/columnstotal] Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

Using @Mr.Wizard advice,

```
HistogramList[dataA, {-0.5, 6.5, 1}, "PDF"][[2]]
```

yields the same result in one hit.